# how to generate a table in postgresql so that one column's value can be generated based on another column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a table in which I can generate a column value based on another column value.

For instance:

| id (primary key)(identity)(int) | temp_id (varchar) | desc (varchar) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | temp1 | hello |
| 2 | temp2 | hello brother |

temp_id column's value should be set automatically like ('temp' + id) based on id's value of that row.

I tried to go through [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71573504/set-value-of-a-column-based-on-another-column) but was unable to achieve my goal.

Comment: You can use a trigger that checks when a new row is inserted into the table, then automatically updates the value for the "*temp_id*" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generated column:

```
create table the_table 
(
  id int primary key generated always as identity,
  temp_id text generated always as ('temp'||id::text) stored,
  "desc" text
);
```

But why store this at all? A view that returns that expression would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank You very much for the code and the advice that you gave me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in such cases, it is not necessary to update any field, it is enough to generate and display this field every time you write select.

```
select *, 'temp' || id::text as temp_id from table
```

Or you can create view only one time and use this anytime anywhere:

```
create view tableview as 
select *, 'temp' || id::text as temp_id from table;

select * from tableview;
```

*If you need this field only in table then you can use generate always field for during creating this table.*